# UICollectionViewLayout sectionInset not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am doing a horizontal collection view inside vertical collection view. It works perfectly for the vertical collection view. But in the horizontal cv, there are some space at the left side of first cell like the image. I have colored the horizontal collection view into yellow. The UIEdgeInsetMake only works for top, bottom, and right but not to the left. Even if I use the delegate method *insetForSectionAtIndex* also get the same result. Any idea why it didn't work?

[image]

The vertical cv's cell consist only one collection view within. In the first cell

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
CGFloat itemHeight = [_innerCell intrinsicContentSize].height;
CGFloat itemWidth = (CGRectGetWidth([UIScreen mainScreen]).bounds));

_cvLayout = (id) _collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
_cvLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetMake(0,0,0,0);
_cvLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(itemWidth, itemHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `.contentInset` property of `collectionView`, it will work.

Example code:

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Comment: Sorry it still same, doesn't make any effect.

Comment: remove rest of your code related to collectionView inset.